# Connect PS3 Controller to Nexus 4

Tags: bluetooth, nexus-4, game-controllers

Is it possible to connect a PS3 Controller wireless (bluetooth) to the Google Nexus 4 without rooting it? There was a way on earlier Android versions, i heard.
How about now?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your phone is rooted then one option may be to try the [Sixaxis Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dancingpixelstudios.sixaxiscontroller) app (it's a paid app, but you can test compatibility with your phone using the free [Sixaxis Compatibility Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dancingpixelstudios.sixaxiscompatibilitychecker) app).

The app should work with both official Sixaxis and DualShock 3 Playstation controllers over bluetooth, but due to the non-standard bluetooth protocol used by the PS3 controllers it isn't compatible with all phones, so test first (using the app above), or [check their website](http://www.dancingpixelstudios.com/sixaxiscontroller/about.html).

Comment: The question explicitly asks about non-rooted phones.